# ASPNET MVC ReturnUrl unexpected behavior when an intermediate method requires authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

returnurl is ok when calling login method directly. When its is called by another method requiring authentication the returnurl path is being ADDED to current URL.

```
// GET: /Account/Login
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string ReturnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = ReturnUrl;
        return View();
    }
```

Login.cshtml:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
                        {(... omitted for brevity)
```

Login view is a modal. So it contains following script handling users closing the modal without loggin in:

```
    $("#modalLoginDiv").on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {
    window.location = '@ViewBag.ReturnUrl';
});
```

calling method directly (home navbar) from page

> http://localhost:51003/Gifts/Details/1589

the ReturnUrl value is "/Gifts/Details/1589" , and closing login modal returns page http://localhost:51003/Gifts/Details/1589, as expected

Now, when calling a method that request authentication from following link on same page http://localhost:51003/Gifts/Details/1589:

> http://localhost:51003/messagemanager/ReportThis?productId=1589

```
[HttpGet]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin, Users")]
    public ActionResult ReportThis(int productId)
    {
        ViewBag.productId = productId;
        return View();
    }
```

as ReportThis method requires authentication, Login method is fired and, again, ReturnUrl value in Login method looks just as expected:

> /messagemanager/ReportThis?productId=1589

If I close the login modal without logging in something unexpected happens: while ReturnUrl value passed onto Login method parameter keeps looking fine, browser URL now is

> http://localhost:51003/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fmessagemanager%2FReportThis%3FproductId%3D1589

that is the returnUrl has been added to the account/login URL.
As a collateral result Login modal obviously keeps loading endlessly.

I cannot figure out what causes this unexpected behavior and how to fix it, as ReturnUrl value always looks fine but in first case it correctly replaces previous URL while being called by an intermediate method it is being added to the account/login URL.

Comment: Did you solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use `ReturnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]` instead of `ViewBag.ReturnUrl`

```
Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new {ReturnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] })


[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginInputModel model, string ReturnUrl) {
...
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the suggestions but unfortunately nothing changed. Closing login modal keeps firing http://localhost:51003/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fmessagemanager%2FReportThis%3FproductId%3D1589, thus reloading the modal. ReturnUrl querystring was and is correctly valued, the problem is the querystring does not substitute but keeps being ADDED to modal login URL.